# What is constant value of msoTextOrientationHorizontal in VBA?

Tags: vba, com, constants, powerpoint, late-binding

Simple question for late evening...like the header says, what is msoTextOrientationHorizontal?

I wish to late bind the code for controlling MS PowerPoint in VBA, but can't seem to find what would be the constant value of msoTextOrientationHorizontal from the PowerPoint 11.0 library.

```
Dim objPPTApp As Object
Dim oPPSlide As Object
Dim oPPShape As Object
Const ppLayoutBlank = 12

Set objPPTApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set oPPSlide = objPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
Set oPPShape = oPPSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 256, 28)
```

to something like

```
Dim objPPTApp As Object
Dim oPPSlide As Object
Dim oPPShape As Object
Const ppLayoutBlank = 12
Const msoTextOrientationHorizontal= 0 '## Value needed 

Set objPPTApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set oPPSlide = objPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
Set oPPShape = oPPSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 256, 28)
```

Thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library":

```
typedef enum {
    msoTextOrientationMixed = 0xfffffffe, // -2
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal = 1, // <<-- This is the one you need
    msoTextOrientationUpward = 2,
    msoTextOrientationDownward = 3,
    msoTextOrientationVerticalFarEast = 4,
    msoTextOrientationVertical = 5,
    msoTextOrientationHorizontalRotatedFarEast = 6
} MsoTextOrientation;
```

Answer (score 2):

And more generally, you know about the object browser?  Open the app you want to automate (or set a reference to it), then press F2 in the IDE.  You'll be able to search for the constant you're after and find its value in the bottommost pane.